# Executing a shell script in Ansible using win_command

Tags: ansible

I have the following Windows script I am running from my prompt to install Chocolatey:

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command " [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

I am trying to use this in an Ansible playbook the following way:

```
---

- hosts: windows
  tasks:
  - name: Install Chocolatey
    win_command: @"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command " [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

I keep getting Ansible syntax errors and I believe it has something to do with the mixed used of quotations in `win_command` and the fact that the command starts with a special symbol "@". I am not sure how I can wrap the command in single quotes or double quotes as the value for `win_command` uses both quotations at some point. I tested the command locally and the installation is successful.

Comment: You appear to have left of the _actual error_ that you're getting, since the details matter a great deal. That said, yes, you'll want to start of by using the yaml scalar syntax `win_command: >-` and then your `@` line, although if `win_command:` is anything like its `command:` friend, you are not allowed to use `&&` constructs, rather use `win_shell:` which has the super advantage of already being in powershell. Finally, running a `SET` anything in a `win_command:` is just wasting your time, since it will alter that env var for that one cmd.exe then _exit_ and poof.

Comment: Also, in the spirit of the "you're asking the wrong question," [`win_chocolatey:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/chocolatey/chocolatey/win_chocolatey_module.html#requirements) will install chocolatey if it doesn't already exist, so you can similarly save yourself some heartache by using ansible modules as they were designed